# Drop Down animation for Image on Tap

Tags: coronasdk

I have a image declared at some specific location.

```
local deselectButton = display.newImage ( "images/nutritional info/deselectButton.png" )
deselectButton.x = display.contentWidth / 2 - 15
deselectButton.y = display.contentHeight / 2 - 172
deselectButton.id = "0"
nutriinfo:insert(nutriNavBar)
```

When I tap on that image, I want another image to be displayed. That is, this second image should fade in and out every time I click on the above image.

```
local dropDown1 = display.newImage ( "images/nutritional info/dropDown.png" )
dropDown1.x = display.contentWidth / 2 - 75
dropDown1.y = display.contentHeight / 2 - 65
dropDown1:setReferencePoint(display.TopCenterReferencePoint)
```

Comment: please specify that you need 'Drop Down' or 'fade in and out' or both at the same time...

Comment: Both at the same time..I have replied to your answer below.

Answer (score 2):

After your code, just do as follows... This may help you:

```
local function addListener()
  deselectButton:addEventListener("tap",clickFunction)
end

local clickCount = 0
function clickFunction()
  deselectButton:removeEventListener("tap",clickFunction)
  clickCount = clickCount + 1
  if(clickCount%2==1)then
     -- show the image
     transition.to(dropDown1,{time=200,x=dropDown1.x,y=dropDown1.y+100,alpha=1,onComplete=addListener}) -- or parameters as you like
  else
     -- hide the image
     transition.to(dropDown1,{time=200,x=dropDown1.x,y=dropDown1.y-100,alpha=0,onComplete=addListener})
  end
end
deselectButton:addEventListener("tap",clickFunction)
```

**Note:** The above code provides you both drop down as well as fade-in/out effect. But, if you need fade in and fade out effect only, you can eliminate `y` parameter from transition, and if you want the drop down type effect, you can eliminate the `alpha` parameter.

Keep coding............... :)

Comment: krs, thanks for the help. The code is working, but there is a issue. When i click on the first image pretty fast.. the second image is displayed and its not fading out/hide when i click on the first image again..